# Automate a domain join on linux

Tags: linux, rhel, active-directory, domain, cloud

I'm new to Linux and searched the whole day on how to automate a domain join and i didn't find anything. This is the code i came up with.

```
realm join domain.com --user=exampleuser
echo "password"
```

I also tried the expect/send command but got the same outcome, since the "realm join" command finished before the "expect" command could come in play.

```
realm join domain.com --user=exampleuser
expect "Password for exampleuser:\r"
send -- "password\r"
```

I believe the problem is that the "realm join" command finishes before the rest of the script can start. And since the password prompt is a part of that command there could literally stand anything and it wouldn't have an effect on the domain join.

The error i get is always "realm: Couldn't join realm: Joining the domain domain.com failed" If i do the join manually it works fine.
The server has RHEL-7 running on it. Can you please help me?

Comment: That ↑ won't work as you want, because the `echo` statement won't be run until `realm join` has completed. (I don't know if `realm join` will accept a password from _stdin_.)

Comment: are you sure there is no `--password=XXX` option in join parameter ?

Comment: i tried --password=xxx but it didn't work and i also didnt find anything like that online :/

Comment: Yes i did and i got the Error " The --one-time-password argument can not be used with --user". So i tried it without --user and got another Error, but it also wouldn't make sense to join without a user. Thanks for your help tho :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try `echo "password" | realm join domain.com --user=exampleuser`
To feed stdin.

Works with --- `echo "password" | sudo -S "command"` when a command requires sudo.

Comment: It actually works. Thank you soooooo much. You literally saved my week.

Comment: Yayyyy! Glad I could help. Be careful though, because the password get stored in plain sight for anyone with access to your script!

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I do have a solution for that problem tho haha :).